# How to find the Azure Subscription creation date using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-management

Is there a way to find the Creation Date of my Azure Subscription using Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find the creation date as I intended - that is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

All as I know, you can just get the details using the CLI command:

```
az account show --subscription subscriptionId
```

But there is no creation date of the subscription to show. And also when you find the subscription in the Azure portal, you would just find the "PURCHASE DATE" of it. I don't think it's the creation date.

Answer (score 0):

subscription creation date can be pulled from ea.azure.com, but yea access to that portal mean you are super admin for your tenant in azure.